# How to display a text file from a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filewriter

I am working on a math trivia game program and the last part I need is to display the file "Scores.txt" when the user clicks on see scores. The code I have below, low and behold, only produces the actual string "Scores.txt" and not my file. Even if I cant convert the text file to the JOptionPane window the system.out.println would be great too. Any help getting me to displaying my file would be greatly appreciated.

```
JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Check out scores!");
    mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scores.txt");



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a JTextArea to display the text. Then you can just load the text into the text area by using:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
textArea.read(....);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
```

Then you can display the scroll pane in your GUI.

Of course you will want to create a `FileReader` object first. Check out the API or search the forums for more information on using a FileReader or BufferedReader.

Comment: Ok, I think I get where you are going with this. So when the user clicks on the menu item I just create a whole new window that will display the file. I got my file fully working, I just want it to pop up as part of the GUI

Answer (score 1):

The general heuristic for solving this is the same for most any programming problem: reak your problem down into constituent steps and solve each one:

- Get the File or resource with the text in it
- Try to open this and read from it. Test that this works by using println's to see the text in the console.
- Place text into a JTextArea via `setText()` with a defined number of rows and columns.
- Place that JTextArea into a JScrollPane
- Place that JScrollPane into a JOptionPane.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,In this code you open your file from any location and get file text or content in JOptionPane.

```
try
    { 
    String filetext="",filecontent="";

    File file=new File("C:\\taqweresanshp.txt");
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    while(fr !=null)
    {
           filetext=br.readLine();
           sb.append(filetext);
           sb.append("\n");
    }
    filecontent=sb.toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File is"+filecontent);

    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
```